# Is using mixin with no parameter is more efficient than using extend

Tags: html, css

I have gone through many articles online and totally got confused.
Could someone clarify on below

Is using mixin with no parameter is more efficient than using extend

Comment: Are you using SASS?

Comment: yes.We are using SAAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending a class will add the styles just once, and add all the selectors that the style needs to be applied to alongside where it's defined. A mixin on the other hand, will copy the styles individually to each selector where you've included it.

Here's what I mean.

### Mixin

```
@mixin mixin(){
    color: blue;
}

.selector-1{
     @include mixin();
}

.selector-2{
     @include mixin();
}
```

**Compiles to**

```
.selector-1 {
    color: blue;
}
.selector-2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

---

### Extending a class

```
.extend{
    color: blue;
}

.selector-1{
    @extend .extend;
}

.selector-2{
    @extend .extend;
}
```

**Compiles to**

```
.extend, .selector-1, .selector-2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

So in terms of efficiency, extending a class will result in a smaller compiled file size, which is why Sass offers the `extend` feature in the first place.